# set GoogleMap widget gesturehandling to "greedy" on flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, google-maps, dart

I'm working on a flutter web application and I'm using GoogleMap widget.
There are several [interaction modes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.gestureHandling) (gestureHandling) that google makes available in the JavaScript version ([Interaction doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction)).

By default, the map is in "greedy" mode, but when I resize the internet browser, it goes into "cooperative" mode ... and at this time, when I want to zoom on my map, I have to maintain CTRL key and i dont't like it at all.

It show me : "Use ctrl + scroll to zoom the map".

So in my project I want to set the map in the "greedy" interaction mode, but the GoogleMap widget doesn't have any parameter for doing it.

I found an alternative solution which consists of going through JavaScript to programmatically press the CTRL button when there is an action of the wheel on the map.

```html
<!-- In web/index.html -->
<!-- ... -->
<head>
  <!-- ... -->
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <!-- ... -->
</head>
<!-- ... -->
```

```js
// In web/script.js
function initScrollListener(id) {
    try {
        var map = document.getElementById('plugins.flutter.io/google_maps_' + id);
        map.addEventListener('wheel', wheelEvent, true);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

function wheelEvent(event) {
    Object.defineProperty(event, 'ctrlKey', { value: true });
}
```

```flutter
// In lib/main.dart (or anywhere in your project)
import 'dart:js' as js;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

//... in my widget ...//
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
      //...//
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
        //Call the JavaScript function
        if(kIsWeb) js.context.callMethod('initScrollListener', [controller.mapId]);
      },
    );
  }
//...//
```

It works pretty well, but I'm not too confident about this solution.

I'm now trying to find a way to retrieve the google.maps.Map instance, and attempt to manualy set the "greedy" interaction mode onto it.

If you have any suggest ^^
Thanks !

related resources:

- [Flutter issue 95774](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/95774)
- [Flutter pull 3943](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/3943)

Comment: Might be worth following up on https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/3943